# jQuery LightBox( SlimBox): How to populate an ASPX file inside it?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am having an ASPX page and i m trying to using jQuery light box(slimbox).I am able to invoke the Lightbox.Now i want to show the content of another page in this lightbox.Ex : I have a data entry form for user registration(signup.aspx).I want to show this when user clicks on the link (which is now showing image in the light box) .Is this possible, If Yes, Willl the evenet handlers work for that ASP page ? ie ;When user enter the data and clicks on the Button,Will it fire a Server side event ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) is only for image content.  See the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/slimbox/wiki/FAQ).  You'll need to make some changes for it to work with an ASPX page.

Quoting from the FAQ:

> Is Slimbox able to display Flash
>   content (like videos), iFrames or
>   other content?
>
> No, Slimbox has been designed from the
>   ground up to display images only, to
>   be simple and to have the smallest
>   code. However, some people have
>   created Slimbox derivatives that
>   implement these features. Because it's
>   open source, you are free to modify
>   the code to fit your needs, as long as
>   you respect the terms of the licence
>   and keep the credits.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used slimbox but if it supports iframe then you should be able to do anything within the box as you can on a regular page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SlimBox supports that. There are plenty of other ways to do it. For example using FaceBox: https://github.com/defunkt/facebox